# How to set read only mode to the JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 JPanels (LeftPanel and RightPanel).

RightPanel has 4 JRadioButtons and one of them were selected by setting `setSelected(true)`.

My requirement is to display the RightPanel in read only mode.

Could you please help me how to achieve this?

```
 JPanel RightPanel=new JPanel();
 RightPanel.removeMouseListener(null);
```

example code will be helpful.

Comment: You could take a look to glassPane, or JLayer to consume events

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to take a look of `JLayer`, you can make your own consuming all events. Take a look into the tutorials [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) . You need Java 7+ for using this class.

Simple Example:

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String args []){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Test checkbox");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Test checkbox"));
        JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
        LayerUI<JComponent> layerUI = new MyLayerUISubclass();
        JLayer<JComponent> jlayer = new JLayer<>(checkbox, layerUI);

        panel.add (jlayer);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }



    static class MyLayerUISubclass extends LayerUI<JComponent>{


        @Override
        public void installUI(JComponent c) {
            super.installUI(c);
            JLayer jlayer = (JLayer)c;
            jlayer.setLayerEventMask(
                    AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK |
                    AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK 
                    );

        }

        @Override
        public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
            JLayer jlayer = (JLayer)c;
            jlayer.setLayerEventMask(0);
            super.uninstallUI(c);
        }


        @Override
        protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer l) {
            e.consume();
        }





        @Override
        protected void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e,
                JLayer<? extends JComponent> l) {
            e.consume();
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option would be that you do a `setEnabled(false);` on all components inside the `JPanel`. You could also use `setEditable(false);` for text components like `JTextField`, `JTextArea`, `JEditorPanel`.

Comment: If I set setEnabled(false) to the JRadioButton components then it wil become greyed out.Is there any way to display as like what we see before?

Comment: *"Is there any way to display as like what we see before?"*  That would be confusing to the user.  I recommend greying it out..